# Arithmetic overflow converting numeric (19,16) to data type numeric (19,19)

Tags: sql, database

Trying to do something pretty trivial (convert a column of type numeric(19, 16) to numeric(19, 19), but keep getting an Arithmetic overflow error.

```
ALTER TABLE X
  ALTER COLUMN Column1 numeric(19,19)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have data that can't fit in a `numeric(19,19)` - how you want to "fix" this is up to you - but you need to review the data that won't fit and decide how to deal with it.

If all of the data fitted, it would run fine:

```
create table X (Column1 numeric(19,16))
create table Y (Column1 numeric(19,16))
insert into X(Column1) values (0.1)
insert into Y(Column1) values (1.0)
```

This works:

```
ALTER TABLE X
  ALTER COLUMN Column1 numeric(19,19)
```

This produces the error:

```
ALTER TABLE Y
  ALTER COLUMN Column1 numeric(19,19)
```

Because you can't put a number with any integral portion into a `numeric(19,19)`.

If you want to find the values that won't fit the changed column definition, run this first:

```
SELECT * FROM X where ABS(Column1) >= 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

NUMERIC(19,19) means you have 19 digits, and all 19 of them behind decimal point - so your largest number that can be stored is 0.9999999999999999999 (19 9s behind 0.)

So, if in your NUMERIC (19,16) column have any values that are larger or equal then 1 - it will fail to convert it to (19,19).

NUMERIC (19,16) can store three digits left of decimal place and 16 behind it -making 999.9999999999999999 largest possible number.

In exapmle, this will work:

```
DECLARE @a NUMERIC(19,16)
SET @a = 0.1234567890123456
SELECT CAST (@a AS NUMERIC(19,19))
```

and this will not:

```
DECLARE @b NUMERIC(19,16)
SET @b = 123.1234567890123456
SELECT CAST (@b AS NUMERIC(19,19))
```

nor this:

```
SELECT CAST (1 AS NUMERIC(19,19))
```

EDIT: Damien_The_Unbeliever has posted a nice select to check for rows that can't fit into (19,19) you should use it if you really want to convert to NUMERIC (19,1) - but, my guess is you don't really want to convert to (19,19) but rather keep your data and just add 3 digits of precision - which is NUMERIC(22,19)